# Lot's of undefined system types in .NETStandard project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I've started using Visual Studio 2017 RC to create a .NETStandard library project.
As long as I target .NETStandard 1.6 VS works fine, but I cannot add a reference to that project from a .NET 4.6.2 console app (Project 'DotNETStandard.csproj' has no target framework compatible with '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2'.)

So I switched to .NETStandard 1.3. Now I can reference the library in the console app, everything compiles and runs fine, but VS is really messed up. Everything is underlined red and I get lots of CS0518 (predefined type System.Int32/System.Double/etc. not defined or imported) errors in the Error List which is really annoying because real compilation errors drown in the overwhelming list of "false" errors.

If I switch the project back to .NETStandard 1.6 VS behaves again as expected.

I searched a lot, but it's hard to find anything useful at all on .NETStandard and VS 2017 problems. What is the problem here and how can I solve it?

**Update**
Restarting VS did the trick. I feel stupid for not trying this sooner. I just closed and reopened the solution which had no effect.

Comment: Do you by any chance use resharper ? I had issues with an older resharper version

Comment: no, no addins at all

Comment: Do check the [.NET Platform support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library) section in the docs, .NETStandard 1.3 requires targeting 4.6.  The VS version you use is also beta quality and a bit doubtful to handle old standards and guaranteed to be buggy, .NETCore is moving fast.  You probably should use .NETStandard 2.0 and 4.6.1, latest and greatest and most likely to be verified for VS2017.  Be sure to report beta bugs at connect.microsoft.com or the corefx GitHub site.

Comment: VS' project property page does only let me choose in the range [1.0, 1.6], I cannot choose .NETStandard 2.0. If I choose the newest I can (1.6), it says it doesn't support :NET 4.6/4.6.1/4.6.2. But if I understand you correctly, this is most likely due to a buggy RC version?